# How to perform Rollback in asp.net when using Stored Procedure

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008

I want to insert data into 12 different tables on a single click of a button. For this I am using single stored procedure. But my problem is when I am doing this and if there is any exception occurs my data is getting inserted partially i.e values is getting inserted in some tables and some remains empty and due to this problem occurs since all are related to one another. So wanted to know is there any way to perform Rollback so that if any exception occurs entire query is rolled back and data is not inserted in any of the table.
This is the code I am currently using for inserting values.

```
public int Sp_InsertUpdateDelete(string s, SqlParameter[] spa)
{
    SqlConnection sc = new SqlConnection(cs);
    sc.Open();
    SqlCommand scm = new SqlCommand(s, sc);
    scm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    foreach (SqlParameter sql in spa)
    {
        scm.Parameters.Add(sql);
    }
    int k = scm.ExecuteNonQuery();
    sc.Close();
    return k;

}



protected void btnHostingSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string select = "select * from tbl_Hosting where Customer_Id='" + ddlCustomerName.SelectedValue + "'";
    DataSet s = gs.select(select);
    if (s.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        Response.Write("<script>alert('Customer Already Exist');</script>");
    }
    else
    {
        if (ddlHosting.SelectedValue == "Yes")
        {
            SqlParameter[] spa = new SqlParameter[29];
            spa[0] = new SqlParameter("@Customer_Id", Convert.ToInt16(ddlCustomerName.SelectedValue));
            spa[1] = new SqlParameter("@Type", 2);
            //Hosting
            if (txtHostingSDate.Text == "" || txtHostingSDate.Text == null)
            {
                spa[2] = new SqlParameter("@Hosting_start_date", null);
            }
            else
            {
                spa[2] = new SqlParameter("@Hosting_start_date", Convert.ToDateTime(txtHostingSDate.Text));
            }
            if (txtHosingEDate.Text == "" || txtHosingEDate.Text == null)
            {
                spa[3] = new SqlParameter("@Hosting_end_date", null);
            }
            else
            {
                spa[3] = new SqlParameter("@Hosting_end_date", Convert.ToDateTime(txtHosingEDate.Text));
            }
            spa[4] = new SqlParameter("@Hosting_provider", ddlHostingPro.SelectedItem.ToString());
            spa[5] = new SqlParameter("@Hosting_type", ddlHostingType.SelectedItem.ToString());
            spa[6] = new SqlParameter("@Hosting_server", ddlHostingServer.SelectedItem.ToString());
            spa[7] = new SqlParameter("@Hosting_total_id", Convert.ToInt16(txtHostingId.Text));
            spa[8] = new SqlParameter("@Hosting_mail_tracking", ddlHostingMailTracking.SelectedItem.ToString());
            spa[9] = new SqlParameter("@Hosting_mail_tracking_users", Convert.ToInt16(txtHostingMtUser.Text));
            spa[10] = new SqlParameter("@Hosting_dns", ddlHostingDns.SelectedItem.ToString());
            spa[11] = new SqlParameter("@Hosting_mail", ddlHostingMail.SelectedItem.ToString());
            spa[12] = new SqlParameter("@Hosting_web", ddlHostingWeb.SelectedItem.ToString());
            spa[13] = new SqlParameter("@Hosting_manage_dns", ddlHostingMngDns.SelectedItem.ToString());

            if (ddlHostingDns.SelectedValue == "No" && (ddlHostingMail.SelectedValue == "Yes" || ddlHostingWeb.SelectedValue == "Yes"))
            {
                spa[14] = new SqlParameter("@Hosting_ns1", txtNS1.Text);
                spa[15] = new SqlParameter("@Hosting_ns2", txtNS2.Text);
            }
            else
            {
                spa[14] = new SqlParameter("@Hosting_ns1", ddlHostingNS1.SelectedItem.ToString());
                spa[15] = new SqlParameter("@Hosting_ns2", ddlHostingNS2.SelectedItem.ToString());
            }


            spa[16] = new SqlParameter("@Hosting_rec_ip", txtHostingARecordIp.Text);
            spa[17] = new SqlParameter("@Hosting_mx_rec1", txtMXRecord1.Text);
            spa[18] = new SqlParameter("@Hosting_mx_rec2", txtMXRecord2.Text);
            spa[19] = new SqlParameter("@Hosting_mx_ip1", txtHostingMxIp1.Text);
            spa[20] = new SqlParameter("@Hosting_space", ddlHostingSpace.SelectedItem.ToString());
            spa[21] = new SqlParameter("@Hosting_mx_ip2", txtHostingMxIp2.Text);
            spa[22] = new SqlParameter("@Hosting_data_transfer", ddlhostingDataTrans.SelectedItem.ToString());
            spa[23] = new SqlParameter("@Hosting_manage_dns_amt", txtHostingMangDnsAmt0.Text);
            spa[24] = new SqlParameter("@Hosting_amt", txtHostingAmt0.Text);
            spa[25] = new SqlParameter("@Hosting_c_ns1", txtHostingNS1.Text);
            spa[26] = new SqlParameter("@Hosting_c_ns2", txtHostingNS2.Text);
            spa[27] = new SqlParameter("@Hosting_c_ns3", txtHostingNS3.Text);
            spa[28] = new SqlParameter("@Hosting_c_ns4", txtHostingNS4.Text); 
int k = gs.Sp_InsertUpdateDelete("Sp_Hosting", spa);  
if (k > 0)
            {
                Response.Write("<script>alert('Hosting Added Success');</script>");
            }
            Clear();

        }
```

Comment: Use a database transaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection())
{
   try
   {
    conn.Open();

    SqlTransaction tran = conn.BeginTransaction("Transaction1");
Cmd = new SqlCommand(sQuery, Conn);
Cmd.Transaction = tran;
    //Your Code

    tran.Commit(); //both are successful
   }
   catch(Exception ex)
   {
      //if error occurred, reverse all actions. By this, your data consistent and correct
      tran.Rollback();
   }
}
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a90c30fy.aspx

Comment: I am getting some error using this code. `Error 56 The type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlTransaction' has no constructors defined` so can you please provide me with edition in my code

Comment: Pass transaction name in Constructor parameter.

Comment: Now getting another exception `ExecuteNonQuery requires the command to have a transaction when the connection assigned to the command is in a pending local transaction.  The Transaction property of the command has not been initialized.`

Comment: Cmd = new SqlCommand(sQuery, Conn);
Cmd.Transaction = Transc;

Comment: I have edit code , in this use Sqlcommand object and assign Transaction to that command object.

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify your Stored procedure and use Transactions for this feature.

Something like this:

```html
DECLARE @TranName VARCHAR(20);
SELECT @TranName = 'MyTransaction';

BEGIN TRANSACTION @TranName;
USE AdventureWorks2012;
DELETE FROM AdventureWorks2012.HumanResources.JobCandidate
    WHERE JobCandidateID = 13;

COMMIT TRANSACTION @TranName;
GO
```

[MSDN Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms188929.aspx)