# How to implement logic similar to transactions while calling multiple stored procedures in foreach loop

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, asp.net-core

I have code similar to below where I need to loop through multiple stored procedures and execute each stored procedure independently. My requirement is if any of stored procedures throws an exception, I need to roll back other stored procedure's actions as well.

We have implemented transactions in each stored procedure, it will roll back data only in that particular specific stored procedure operation.

I want to roll back other stored procedure operations as well if any of stored procedures throws an exception.

How can I do that?

```
var multipleProcNamesList = new List<string>();

multipleProcNamesList.Add("Usp_InsertData");
multipleProcNamesList.Add("Usp_DeleteData");
multipleProcNamesList.Add("Usp_UpdateData");

foreach (string procName in multipleProcNamesList)
{
    // sending this current procedure to azure logic app for call respective stored procedure
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to perform Rollback in asp.net when using Stored Procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30449899/how-to-perform-rollback-in-asp-net-when-using-stored-procedure)

Comment: Here I'm not using SqlCommand, calling stored proc through logic app by http call.

Comment: if you don't have direct access to the proc the you can't roll it back. You need to amend the logic app. Either that or you amend the SQL so you have one master stored proc which calls all the others and wraps those calls in a transaction within the master procedure.

Comment: @ADyson, I too got same idea.I'm going with master stored proc now.